# SSIS Package Loading into Excel file

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, ssis-2012

We are trying to load a excel file from SQL table which has more than 20 million records though SSIS Package deployed to integration services catalog 2014. getting following error-

"The buffer manager failed a memory allocation call for 1000000 bytes, but was unable to swap out any buffers to relieve memory pressure. 12 buffers were considered and 15 were locked. Either not enough memory is available to the pipeline because not enough are installed, other processes were using it, or too many buffers are locked."

When we load the same file to CSV or text files the package is loading.

Comment: [\What is the maximum allowed rows in a Microsoft Excel .xls or .xlsx](https://superuser.com/questions/366468/what-is-the-maximum-allowed-rows-in-a-microsoft-excel-xls-or-xlsx#366473)

Comment: MS Excel has a maximum row limit, so you will need to filter te result or use a flat file instead.

Comment: this package worked fine in 2008, after migrating to 2014 we are getting this error

Comment: I very much doubt that the package managed to export 20M rows in excel in BIDS. if it did, did you ever try to open said file? I expect that it was corrupt or missing (a lot of) data. Like @LukaszSzozda has linked, there is a limit to the amount of rows a `xls` and `xlsx` file can contain on a single worksheet (65,536 and 1,048,576 respectively).

Comment: If I recall correctly, the old JET drivers used to just stop at 65,536 rows, even if there were more; they didn't cause an error or anything, it just passed a success value back once it hit the max and if there were further rows JET didn't care for them. ACE on the other hand, at least errors if more than 1,048,576 are passed. I suspect you are now using ACE, and have just found out the hard way that all your old files are missing around 1.94M rows of data.

Comment: You can test if it's a row limit of excel problem.  Just try it with 100 rows, if that works and 20 million break it's most likely a cap you are hitting.

Comment: total row count is less than the excel limit.so no issues with excel

Comment: is there any other way to load the data to excel using SSIS ?